# Is it possible to put html element in aspx if funtion?

Tags: asp.net

Could it possible to put element in if function in ASP.NET like in ASP.NET MVC Razor view?
Maybe something like this :

```
<% if (Visible)
   {
       <div>I want to determine here</div>
   } %>
```

But this will show error... I knew it could solve by using javascript or div with codebehind:

```
<div style="<%=isNotGame? "display:none":"display:block" %>"></div>
```

or:

```
<div runat="server" id="codeBehind"></div>
CodeBehind.InnerHTML="...";
```

Q1: Is it possible? If yes, how?

Q2: Why I want to do this is because I think if I don't want to show an element, it is better not to create the element than create and hide it, is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, try this instead.

```
<% 
   if (Visible)
   {
%>
       <div>I want to determine here</div>
<%
   } 
%>
```

The 2nd question, in my opinion if you don't need it then there is no reason to take up the resources.  Keep in mind that this is all data transferring over the wire.  Depending on how many wasted elements you create it can add up fast and depending on what you are doing it may have a number of adverse affects.  Many people pay for data on mobile devices.  Search engines could penalize you for performance losses due to high volumes of data you never cared to send anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As your original question says about razor syntax, it can be done as -

```
@if (Visible) {
 <div>I want to determine here</div>
}
```

If you want more information on razor syntax, [Check this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/)

Answer to your question 2 is tricky. You can render whatever elements you want and take decision at code behind but if you want to toggle some elements by specific conditions of your scenario then it is better to do it by Javascript as for toggling requesting server to do it for client is bad approach.

Comment: Hi, maybe my original expression is not really clear, I know how to do this in razor, but want to know in aspx, but thanks for question 2, I'm thinking about if I write too many code in view it is hard to maintain.

Comment: Same syntax will work as for MVC to web pages if you have ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) 3 http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate HTML in your razor view, as per your condition

```
@if(condition){
<div>show this div</div>
}
```

And about Question2, do not render unnecessary . But in case you need that HTML to be made visible depending on user actions, then render the HTML, use CSS to hide the same. And then on client side you can make it visible.

Comment: Thank you but I'm asking about how to write if function in ASP.NET, and Q2 I got ''do not render unnecessary! "